# Material UI + Formik, handleSubmit() doesn't work

Tags: typescript, material-ui, formik, formik-material-ui

I am making a form using Format and Material UI, however when I try to submit the form, nothing happens. I have tried changing button's type, checking initial values and. validation schema. Here is the code of the useFormik and MUI form:

```
  const initialValues = useMemo<Course>(
    () => ({
      category: '',
      name: '',
      grade: '',
      month: '',
      year: '',
    }),
    [],
  );

  const validationSchema = yup.object({
    category: yup.string().required(t('errors:cannotBeEmpty')),
    name: yup.string().required(t('errors:cannotBeEmpty')),
    grade: yup.string().required(t('errors:pleasePick')),
    month: yup.string().required(t('errors:cannotBeEmpty', { name: t('common:date') })),
    year: yup.number().required(t('errors:cannotBeEmpty', { name: t('common:date') })),
  });

  const { values, touched, errors, handleChange, setFieldValue, handleSubmit, isSubmitting, resetForm } =
    useFormik<any>({
      initialValues,
      validationSchema,
      onSubmit: async ({ category, name, grade, month, year }, { setErrors }) => {
           console.log(values);
        // const date = new Date(year, month);
        // try {
        //   await dispatch(actions.createGlance({ name: gpa, grade, date, category }));
        //   setMessageModalVisible(true);
        // } catch (err) {
        //   if (err.message) {
        //     toast.error(err.message);
        //   }
        //   setErrors(err.errors ?? {});
        // }
      },
      enableReinitialize: true,
    });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!open) {
      resetForm();
    }
  }, [resetForm, open]);

  return (
    <mui.Modal open={open} onClose={onClose}>
      <mui.Box sx={modalStyle}>
        <mui.Box sx={closeButton}>
          <img style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} src={CloseIcon} alt="close-icon" onClick={onClose} />
        </mui.Box>
        <mui.Box sx={{ textAlign: 'center', width: '506px', margin: '0 auto' }}>
          <mui.Typography sx={modalTitle}>{t('profile.student.transcriptScreen.addTests')}</mui.Typography>
          <mui.Typography sx={modalSubTitle}>
            {t('profile.student.transcriptScreen.addYourFinalGrade')}
            <mui.Typography onClick={openLetterGradingScaleModal} sx={modalBlueSubTitle}>
              {' '}
              {t('profile.student.transcriptScreen.clickHereToViewScale')}
            </mui.Typography>
          </mui.Typography>
        </mui.Box>
        <mui.FormControl
        <mui.Box style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', margin: '64px 0 16px 0' }}>
          <mui.FormControl style={{ width: '598px' }}>
            <mui.InputLabel id="course-selection-label">
              {t('profile.student.transcriptScreen.selectCourse')}
            </mui.InputLabel>
            <mui.Select
              label={t('profile.student.transcriptScreen.selectCourse')}
              labelId="course-selection-label"
              value={values.category ?? ''}
              name="category"
              onChange={handleChange}
            >
              {categoryOptions.map(({ name, id }) => (
                <mui.MenuItem value={id}>{name}</mui.MenuItem>
              ))}
            </mui.Select>
          </mui.FormControl>
        </mui.Box>
        {values.category !== '' && (
          <mui.Box
            style={{ paddingBottom: '16px', margin: '0 auto', width: '598px', borderBottom: '1px solid #E0E0E0' }}
          >
            <mui.Box style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between', width: '598px', margin: '16px auto' }}>
              <mui.FormControl style={{ width: '48%' }}>
                <mui.InputLabel id="course-name-label">
                  {t('common:subjectCourseName', {
                    subject:
                      values.category === 'SOCIAL_STUDIES'
                        ? 'Social Studies'
                        : values.category.toLowerCase().charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
                          values.category.toLowerCase().slice(1),
                  })}
                </mui.InputLabel>
                <mui.OutlinedInput
                  name="name"
                  value={values.name ?? ''}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  label={t('common:subjectCourseName', {
                    subject:
                      values.category === 'SOCIAL_STUDIES'
                        ? 'Social Studies'
                        : values.category.toLowerCase().charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
                          values.category.toLowerCase().slice(1),
                  })}
                ></mui.OutlinedInput>
              </mui.FormControl>

              <mui.FormControl style={{ width: '48%' }}>
                <mui.InputLabel id="course-grade-label">{t('common:grade')}</mui.InputLabel>
                <mui.Select name="grade" value={values.grade ?? ''} onChange={handleChange} label={t('common:grade')}>
                  {gradeOptions.map(({ name }) => (
                    <mui.MenuItem value={name}>{name}</mui.MenuItem>
                  ))}
                </mui.Select>
              </mui.FormControl>
            </mui.Box>

            <mui.Box style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between', width: '598px', margin: '16px auto' }}>
              <mui.FormControl style={{ width: '48%' }}>
                <mui.InputLabel id="course-semester-label">{t('common:semesterTaken')}</mui.InputLabel>
                <mui.Select
                  name="month"
                  value={values.month ?? ''}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  label={t('common:semesterTaken')}
                >
                  {semesterOptions.map(({ name, id }) => (
                    <mui.MenuItem value={id}>{name}</mui.MenuItem>
                  ))}
                </mui.Select>
              </mui.FormControl>

              <mui.FormControl style={{ width: '48%' }}>
                <mui.InputLabel id="course-year-label">{t('common:yearTaken')}</mui.InputLabel>
                <mui.Select name="year" value={values.year ?? ''} onChange={handleChange} label={t('common:yearTaken')}>
                  {yearOptions.map(({ name }) => (
                    <mui.MenuItem value={+name}>{name}</mui.MenuItem>
                  ))}
                </mui.Select>
              </mui.FormControl>
            </mui.Box>
          </mui.Box>
        )}
        {values.category !== '' && (
          <mui.Box
            style={{
              paddingTop: '32px',
              width: '598px',
              margin: '0 auto',
              display: 'flex',
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
            }}
          >
            <mui.Button style={{ fontWeight: 600 }} variant="outlined">
              {t('common:addMore')}
            </mui.Button>
            <mui.Button type="button" onClick={() => handleSubmit()} style={{ fontWeight: 600 }} variant="contained">
              {t('common:save')}
            </mui.Button>
          </mui.Box>
        )}
      </mui.Box>
    </mui.Modal>
  );
```

I have checked a plenty of other Stackoverflow posts, but none of the responses helped me. I would be really pleased if someone helps me with this issue!
Thank you.